# How can I read data (page by page )from orientDB using flink?

Tags: orientdb, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've developed Apache Flink connector to read data from OrientDB source. It works fine, read the data from the source and put them into a dataset. But, I want to read data using Pagination technique and pull data page by page. Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are using queries?
You can get a limited number of results using this type of query:

```
SELECT FROM <target> [WHERE ...] SKIP <records-to-skip> LIMIT <max-records>
```

Comment: Thanks Oleksandr. I did it using the same query (even faster) using RID to direct access to the first record of the next page. My problem is in Flink side. It provides an interface including Open() and NextRecord() method which let you to open a connection to a datasource such as OrientDB and reading records. But when I open a connection and reading the first page, the connection would be closed and I have to open another one as you know this decreases dramatically the performance if you have many pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can split full dataset into skip-limit batches and run it as separate flink jobs like this [CliFrontend suddenly shotdown during multiple batch jobs processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365757/clifrontend-suddenly-shotdown-during-multiple-batch-jobs-processing) Flink will not read second page before all records of first page will have been processed.

Or you should implement paging logic via flink - group by all records within the single page by page number and then process all page groups with parallelism 1